# Adding Empty Rows with formatting in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet and I want to insert blank rows, but keep the formatting from the previous row. I'm using vba for it because the amount of rows I get is conditional. I have a version that works, but I want to make it more efficient. My version right now just inserts the rows one by one. So it is pretty slow. Is there a way to just insert all the rows at once?

I already know the amount of rows to insert so I really just need how to insert many rows at once in vba.

Here is the way I'm doing it now.

```
For i = 5 To (selectionRows + 4)
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Rows(i + 1).Copy
        Rows(i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone
        Rows(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Next i
```

Comment: It's quite easy to copy one row over to multiple rows using the following and thus passing a row range as destination. `Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Rows("2:20")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Rows(5).Resize(selectionRows).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove'
```